# SkiaSharp Invalid Cast Exception

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

Receiving an `InvalidCastException` in `LoadApplication(new App());`.
I have added SkiaSharp and SkiaSharp.Views.Forms in both PCL and Android. It also automatically added SkiaSharp.Views package to the Android project.

I removed all complex code and left this part in my XAML file

```
<ContentView 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:skia="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.Forms"     
    x:Class="SkiaSharpRemote.MediaControlView">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <!--<skia:SKCanvasView
            x:Name="canvas"
            VerticalOptions="Fill"
            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
            PaintSurface="Canvas_PaintSurface">
        </skia:SKCanvasView>-->
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

The app loaded after I commented out the `skCanvasView` line. If I uncomment it, the following exception is thrown.

> at (wrapper castclass) System.Object:__castclass_with_cache
>   (object,intptr,intptr)   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Registrar`1[TRegistrable].GetHandler (System.Type type)
>   [0x0001b] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Registrar.cs:24
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Registrar`1[TRegistrable].GetHandler[TOut]
>   (System.Type type) [0x00000] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Registrar.cs:29
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00006] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:288
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.AddChild
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view,
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer oldRenderer,
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.RendererPool pool, System.Boolean
>   sameChildren) [0x00023] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:74
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.SetElement
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement oldElement, Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement
>   newElement) [0x00104] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:207
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.Load ()
>   [0x00000] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:58
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetPackager
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager packager)
>   [0x00007] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:337
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement
>   (TElement element) [0x00111] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:196
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00027] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:129
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x0001f] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:289
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.AddChild
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view,
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer oldRenderer,
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.RendererPool pool, System.Boolean
>   sameChildren) [0x00023] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:74
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.SetElement
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement oldElement, Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement
>   newElement) [0x00104] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:207
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.Load ()
>   [0x00000] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:58
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetPackager
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager packager)
>   [0x00007] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:337
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement
>   (TElement element) [0x00111] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:196
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00027] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:129
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x0001f] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:289
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.AddChild
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view,
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer oldRenderer,
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.RendererPool pool, System.Boolean
>   sameChildren) [0x00023] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:74
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.SetElement
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement oldElement, Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement
>   newElement) [0x00104] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:207
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.Load ()
>   [0x00000] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:58
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetPackager
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager packager)
>   [0x00007] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:337
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement
>   (TElement element) [0x00111] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:196
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00027] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:129
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x0001f] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:289
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.Platform.AddChild
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, System.Boolean layout) [0x00015] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\Platform.cs:250
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.Platform.SetPage
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Page newRoot) [0x00089] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\Platform.cs:239
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.InternalSetPage
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Page page) [0x0009b] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FormsAppCompatActivity.cs:374
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.SetMainPage
>   () [0x00000] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FormsAppCompatActivity.cs:444
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.LoadApplication
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Application application) [0x00183] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FormsAppCompatActivity.cs:135
>   at SkiaSharpRemote.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle
>   bundle) [0x0002e] in
>   /Users/simonlam/Desktop/Samples/Xamarin/SkiaRemote/SkiaSharpRemote/Droid/MainActivity.cs:25
>   at
>   Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_
>   (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr
>   native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in
>   <27c17fe440cf491ba8255bcefade6e02>:0    at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   System.Object:a050e315-9322-4894-b9ce-8db88ad775ab
>   (intptr,intptr,intptr)

The error didn't tell me much, I only see this is some kind of casting error.

I have another project which have used skiasharp as well. I basically follow the same route but for this project it didn't work.

Comment: The beginning of the exception message is missing

Comment: It working now.. maybe i have to clean the android project and rebuild again...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Add SkiaSharp.Views.Forms NuGet to all projects! (The PCL/Shared,
   Android and iOS project.)
2. Then clean and rebuild your solution.

That will solve your issue.